# How would you go about packaging up an existing windows machine as a VM image?

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, backup, virtual-machine, upgrade

I'm thinking of upgrading a machine from windows XP to Windows 7 I was wondering if there was a sensible way to package up the existing machine's OS/Data/Installed Apps so that I could load it up in a VM from Windows 7, possibly using the built in Windows XP mode in Windows 7 Pro/Ultimate.

Comment: What are you going to use to run your VM? WMWare workstation, or other?

Comment: Windows 7 Pro/Ultimate (I think) allow you to install MS Virtual PC (Or Windows virtual PC) for free to run windows XP mode. So preferably that. Unless VMWare offer a similar free product. I only want it in case I need to run any old software I have installed on the machine that I might forget to install/can't find anymore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Sysinternals Disk2VHD](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/ee656415) tool, it's free and it creates vhd files that's used by Microsofts virtualization tools.

Remember that if your current OS install is using an OEM license you will likely get licensing issues and not be able to validate it after a physical to virtual(p2v) migration.